# Ember data - child relations not marked as "isDirty"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having trouble with isDirty and the fact it doesn't seem to be affected by related child models...

I created a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJu27/1/) to try and explain. If you edit my name, isNotDirty computed property becomes false. If you re-run the page and edit a child model, it doesn't change isNotDirty...

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isNotDirty: Em.computed.not('isDirty')
});
```

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make a computed property that monitors isDirty on all the child records, like this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isNotDirty: function() {
        return !this.get('projects').someProperty('isDirty');
    }.property('projects.@each.isDirty')
});
```

You can also make a property that takes the parent record's dirty state into account:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isParentOrAnyChildDirty: function() {
        return this.get('isDirty') || this.get('projects').someProperty('isDirty');
    }.property('isDirty', 'projects.@each.isDirty')
});
```

Comment: Cheers alexspeller, your help on here and the emberjs IRC is invaluable. I've learnt quite a bit from you so far - thanks again!